# How can I make Plotly charts adapt to any screen they are viewed on?

Tags: python, css, plotly

I have some Plotly Express charts which are stored on Chart Studio. I would like to create blog posts in which I would include some of those charts. The problem is that the charts appear fine on computer screens, but many things start to be off when viewed on mobile phones (width and font, mainly).

I know about the `autosize` argument, which helps in certain regards, but most of the time the font remains off and does not adjust. I guess that it is because it is set to a certain size, so it cannot dynamically adjust, but I don't know how to do it. My questions are thus:

- Is there a parameter that can allow me to adjust the font dynamically, based on the screen size, too?
- If not, should I use some CSS within the website in which I am going to embed the chart? Would something like:

```
<style>
    .plotly-text {
        font-size: 5vw; /* Relative font size */
        }
</style>
```

do the trick?

Thanks a lot for any advice you could give me. As is probably obvious, I'm no dev, so many things probably elude me, and apologies if my question is poorly formulated.

In case that is useful, here is the Chart Studio link to one of the charts that is very off when viewed on mobile:

[https://plotly.com/~MichaelGauthier/4/](https://plotly.com/%7EMichaelGauthier/4/)

And here is the Plotly Express code for it:

```
df['Color'] = pd.cut(df['Value'], 
    bins=[0, 23.4, 46.8, 70.2, float("inf")],
    labels=['green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red'],
    include_lowest=True)

fig = px.treemap(df, 
    path=['Area'], 
    values='Value', 
    color='Color', 
    color_discrete_map={'green': 'green', 'yellow': 'yellow', 'orange': 'orange','red': 'red'},
    title='Average Meat Consumption per Capita per Country in 2021',
    custom_data = ['Area', 'Value'],)

fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor='black', plot_bgcolor='black', title=dict(text='<b>Average Meat Consumption per Capita per Country in 2021 (in kg)</b>', 
    font=dict(color='white'), y = 0.98), autosize = True,
    annotations=[
        dict(x=0,
            y=1.10,
            xref='paper',
            yref='paper',
            text='<i><span style="color: white;">Based on the <a href="https://reseauactionclimat.org/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/rac_alimentation-synthese-08-webpage.pdf" style="color: cyan; background-color: black; padding: 20px;">2024 recommendations</a> of the French "Programme National Nutrition Santé" of no more than 450g of meat per week / 23.4kg per year</i></span><br><b><span style="color: green;">Sustainable consumption</span></b>' '<b><span style="color: yellow; background-color: black; padding: 20px;"> Up to 2x the yearly limit</span></b>' '<b><span style="color: orange;"> Up to 3x the yearly limit</span></b>' '<b><span style="color: red;"> More than 3x the yearly limit</span></b><br><b><span style="color: white;"><a href="https://www.fao.org/faostat/en/#data/FBS" style="color: cyan; background-color: black; padding: 20px;">Data</a>: FAO (2024)</span></b>',
            align='left',
            showarrow=False,
            font=dict(size=12))   
    ])

fig.update_traces(
    hovertemplate="<br>".join([
        "%{customdata[0]}",
        "%{customdata[1]}"]))

fig.update_traces(
    hovertemplate=''
)
```

Don't hesitate to tell me if you need any other information, I'll try to be as reactive as possible!